# Pad the inside of a SwiftUI frame?

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to pad the Left and Right text in this screenshot using SwiftUI? If this were HTML, I would use `padding-left` and `padding-right` in CSS. Alas, SwiftUI requires a different way of thinking.

[image]

Now that I've got these two nice frames working the way I want them to, what's the technique for shifting that text inside the frame. How can "Left" be scooted slightly to the right moving it away from the left edge and giving it some nice visual space? The same technique can be applied oppositely to the "Right" text.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
  HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("Left")
      .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.33, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
      .background(Color.yellow)
    Text("Right")
      .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.67, height: 50, alignment: .trailing)
      .background(Color.orange)
  }
}
.padding()
```

Comment: Something like `Text("Left").padding(.leading, 20)` (not tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI the order of modifiers is important. See:

- [Order of modifiers in SwiftUI view impacts view appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56450804/8697793)

---

In the below code you apply `.background(Color.yellow)` first and then `.padding()` to the whole `GeometryReader`. This means that the padding is *outside* the `Text("Left")`.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
  HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("Left")
      .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.33, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
      .background(Color.yellow)
    Text("Right")
      .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.67, height: 50, alignment: .trailing)
      .background(Color.orange)
  }
}
.padding()
```

What you need is to also add `padding` just after the `Text` views:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
  HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("Left")
      .padding(.leading) // add here
      .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.33, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
      .background(Color.yellow)
    Text("Right")
      .padding(.trailing) // add here
      .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.67, height: 50, alignment: .trailing)
      .background(Color.orange)
  }
}
.padding()
```

Note that you can specify the *direction* of the padding (e.g. `.padding(.trailing)`) as well as the *offset*:

```
.padding(.trailing, 10)
```

---

Also note that you need to add padding *before* `frame` - otherwise the total width of your view will be:

```
0.33 * GeometryReader width + 0.67 * GeometryReader width + width of `.padding(.leading)` + width of `.padding(.trailing)`
```

and it will be more than the width returned by `GeometryReader`.