# SwiftUI - corner radius changes the height of an image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If the `.cornerRadius` modifier comes after the `.frame` modifier, the image becomes much slower. What is the reason behind this ?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 100) {
            Image("image1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 343, height: 184)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            Image("image1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .frame(width: 343, height: 184)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: simulator screenshot:]

Comment: Order of modifiers is important. The `cornerRadius` is clipping, but `frame` is not.

Comment: That's right, I just checked the documentation and it says "Clips this view to its bounding frame, with the specified corner radius"

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI the order of modifiers is important and can lead to a different output.

A rule of thumb is:

1. read them from bottom to top
2. understand that every modifier produce a new view
3. the modifier "modifies" only what's below:

```swift
-> .frame(width: 343, height: 184)
 -> .cornerRadius(8)
  -> .scaledToFill()
   -> .resizable()
```

Since you used the `cornerRadius` the documentation states that:

> Clips this view to its bounding frame, with the specified corner
> radius.

Behind the scene, you can imagine the engine applying two modifiers, the clipped and the corner radius.

[image]

Because every modifier produces a new view when the clipping is calculated it's like it doesn't know what are the bounds in which constrain the new view and that explains why the image goes out.

If we go a step further where we try to apply two `frame` and `cornerRadius` hopefully should be clearer how SwiftUI interprets the modifiers:

[image]

If you want to know more, this discussion goes deeper into the details of how SwiftUI sees the modifier: [Order of modifiers in SwiftUI view impacts view appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450804/order-of-modifiers-in-swiftui-view-impacts-view-appearance)